# Do Unchained Monks have weapon proficiency with all monk weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, monk

[Monk Unchained](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained) says the following about weapon proficiencies:

> Monks are proficient with the club, crossbow (light or heavy), dagger, handaxe, javelin, kama, nunchaku, quarterstaff, sai, short sword, shortspear, shuriken, siangham, sling, spear, **and any weapon with the monk special weapon quality.**

There is [an FAQ/Errata](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1g1#v5748eaic9okw) that is a bit dated in comparison linked on the Pathfinder SRD:

> Q: If a weapon is specified as a monk weapon, does that mean that monks are automatically proficient with that weapon?
>
> A: No. It means that they can use this weapon while using flurry of blows. It does not mean that it is added to the list of weapons that a monk is proficient with, unless the weapon description says otherwise.

Are unchained monks now proficient with monk weapons?

This came up because a player in our group wanted to use unchained monk BUT wanted to use a monk weapon ['seven-branched sword'](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sword-seven-branched) which doesn't specify it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

[Regular monks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk) weren't given proficiency with monk weapons. That FAQ applies to them. It isn't about the Unchained monks. As you note, it's old, and Unchained monks didn't even exist at that point.

[Unchained monks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/monk-unchained) *are* given a weapon proficiency with any monk weapon, hence the bit you bolded.

Answer (score 3):

That FAQ predates Unchained. Presumably, this is exactly the *reason* they decided to rewrite the monk weapon proficiencies (prior to Unchained, monks did **not** say they were proficient with all monk weapons), so that you *could* do exactly what your player would like to do.

Certainly, the monk can be safely allowed to use such weapons.